# Error during installing pandas on command line in windows

Tags: python-3.x

During installing pandas package through command prompt 
using statement  - `pip install pandas`

I am getting an error as shown below -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in <module>
    import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```